# Is “In following, ...” acceptable in place of “In the following, ...”?

Tags: grammaticality, definite-articles

In editing a [recent question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80405/it-might-be-defined-different-differently), I wrote:

> In following, `realtype` stands for ...

Later, it got edited (two words were added) to read:

> In the following example, `realtype` stands for ...

The latter edit is incorrect because `realtype` stands for the same thing in the whole question, not just in the example; but for the purpose of this question, that's minor and doesn't matter.  The real question is whether *in following* is acceptable; is there any semantic or grammatical error with using *in following* instead of  *in the following*?

I realize that *in following* is used only infrequently when *in the following* might be used in its place.  In instances I looked at after a Google Books search, it was used mostly by Indian or German speakers of English; for example:

> ... the most relevant constraints ... are summarized in following. – *Valuation of Network Effects in Software Markets*, Andreas Kemper, 2009

Note, this question is not about how frequently one phrase or another is used; it's not about personal preferences or other ways to say the same thing; instead, it asks if use of *in following* violates any important English-language tenets.

Comment: As a German, *in following* indeed sounds fine to my ears because we commonly say "Im Folgenden" in German whereas using *the* would definitely need a noun, e.g. "In dem folgenden Abschnitt". - However, what I just want to say, that I'm not really surprised about your finding.

Answer (score 5):

As you found in your research, this may be dialectal. In British English, *the* is required to turn *following* into an adjective, rather than having it parsed as a verb.

*In following [something]* → the something is being followed
*In the following [something]* → the something follows

> - In following their officers’ orders, the Light Brigade charged into history.
> - In following examples, we learn from others  [Verb: “*By* following examples”]
> - In the following examples, we learn from others [Adjective: “In the examples which follow this sentence”]

Context may allow the [something] to be omitted.

> - The officers gave orders to the men. In following [those orders], they rode to oblivion.
> - In the following [example], `realtype` stands for...

That is, in British English at least, a present participle is prioritised as a verb when used with *in* like this, and it needs *the* if it is to be parsed as an adjective.

Comment: @jwpat7 My sincerest apologies. I believe the rule Andrew Leach describes appies to American English as well.  When I see "in following", it implies "in the process of following".  It stuck out to me as incorrect because of the lack of a definite article. I would not have added "example", but the system would not allow a three letter correction.  Honestly, the lack of an article did not prevent understanding. I'll research first in future editing attempts.

Comment: @Mike Your edit follows what I wrote and I think it was correct. *In following* for *in the following* is non-standard, in my experience.

Comment: Understood. That is why I posted the comment under your answer. Thank you.